# @section('content') in Laravel 5.2 seems not to work on a creation route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to visit the `/create` route, but it displays the navbar with a blank page. It should however be the content from a section.

[image: Create Page]

Here's the example:

```
@extends('layout')
@section('content')
    <p>The create form.Tl:dr.</p>
@stop
```

I also made an edit page, and it works fine, **with the exactly same code** (unless the method, it's different).

[image: Edit Page]

The problem began after I ran `php artisan make:auth`, but I don't think that is the source of this error.

The controller: https://codeshare.io/xpJm3
The routes: https://codeshare.io/QBxxw

Comment: Can you display the code for your controller and route please?

Comment: Thanks for fixing my grammar, wait I'll post the controller and the route.

Comment: I have added controller and the routes.

Comment: Where's the routes code it seems I'm not able to see those code

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the routes, hehe.

Comment: Are your a view templates properly named?

Comment: Yeah, the name is layout.blade.php

Comment: Solved, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

How to solve it:

1. Check your logs files on `..\storage\logs\laravel.log`. Makes sure you delete all logs so you can easily find the newest log.
2. Reload the pages who have error.
3. Back to the logs files, if you see the error like:

   ```
   RuntimeException in compiled.php line xxx: No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.
   ```
4. Check your `config\app.php` . Search for `'cipher' => 'somekey'` , change the `somekey` value to `'AES-256-CBC'`
5. Reload the page again.
6. If you still can't see the content like what happened to me before, run this command on your root directory:

   `php artisan key:generate`

Now, you're done.

Added:
Also, don't forget add this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

To your controller.